# NodeJS + CoffeeScript Workflow

Tags: node.js, workflow, coffeescript

I have recently started learning nodeJS. Being a long-time coffeescript lover I naturally decided to use it along with node. Writing long-running processes with node I found myself restarting the program frequently. After a quick google I found [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor). Node-supervisor simply watches the current directory for file changes and restarts your app for you automatically.

Before I started using supervisor I was using coffeescript with the `--watch` option to automatically recompile my coffescripts when they changed.

So the problem is this, supervisor and the coffeescript recompiler don't play nice together.

- First I run `coffee --compile --watch .`
- Then in a new terminal I run `supervisor app.js`

After that supervisor keeps restarting my app forever, even when there has been no changes to the source files.

**So the question is this, what is your workflow for working with nodeJS and CoffeeScript?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are doing is some kind of redundant.

Here are some hints:

- after installing CoffeeScript you have an executable called `coffee` so you can do (no need to compile your coffee-script files):

  `coffee yourfile.coffee`
- how to combine this with `supervisor`?
  if you would have read the [Readme](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor#node-supervisor--) on the Github page you would have noticed that supervisor can execute CoffeeScript files, too. All you need to do is:

  `supervisor yourfile.coffee`

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Thanks.